# How to see Parse Server cloud code logs?

Tags: parse-platform, bitnami, parse-server

I have Bitnami's Parse Server set up on Azure.

I'm logging some info from cloud code using console.log and console.error. When using hosted Parse these logs were displayed in the Info & Error Logs section on the Dashboard. Any idea where the logs go to now?

The issue is not specific to Bitnami's distribution. I also tested on a local machine with parse-server-example & Parse Dashboard and got the same result (no logs).

Comment: I found this suggestion for redirecting the log to a file: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/781#issuecomment-193147472 . This doesn't completely solve the problem as the logs are not picked up by Parse Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I use AWS but you can see the logs by downloading them or running it on localhost just cd into your folder then do `Npm start` on terminal and switch you parse server URL to http://localhost:1337/parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download them through the azure cli

Take a look here for installation : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/

I used npm : `npm install azure-cli -g`

open up terminal and type in : `azure site log download webappname`

This will save the logs for the web app named 'webappname' to a file named diagnostics.zip in the current directory.

Unzip and open the folder diagnostics -> LogFiles -> Application

The text file with `-stderr-` in the name of it will display the logs you display by using `console.error()` in your cloud code.

The text file with `-stdout-` in the name of it will display the logs you display by using `console.log()` in your cloud code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on Bitnami Parse. We are working on fixing it for the next release.

You have to log in your server via SSH and modify the line below at the `/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/server.js` file:

From:

```
cloud: "./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js",
```

To:

```
cloud: "./cloud/main.js",
```

You have to include the path to the `./cloud/main.js` you previously created (assuming you created it in `/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/`).

Remember to restart the Server after applying those changes running:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```